# Using Bash to replace DOTS or characters in DIRECTORY / SUBDIRECTORY names

Tags: bash, ubuntu, find, ubuntu-14.04, rename

I have searched looking for the right solution. I have found some close examples.[Bash script to replace spaces in file names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709619/3818865)
But what I'm looking for is how to replace multiple `.`dots in current DIRECTORY/SUBDIRECTORY names, then replace multiple `.`dots in FILENAMES excluding the *.extention "recursively".

This example is close but not right:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "*.*" -execdir rename 's/./-/g' "{}" \;
```

another example but not right either:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f//./-}"; done
```

So

> dir.dir.dir/dir.dir.dir/file.file.file.ext

Would become

> dir-dir-dir/dir-dir-dir/file-file-file.ext

Comment: Assuming you can use perlre, this is the re you need: `(?<!^)\.(?=.*\.)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to escape `.` in regular expressions (such as the ones used for `rename`, because by default it has the special meaning of "any single character". So the replacement statement at least should be `s/\./-/g`.
2. You should *not* quote `{}` in `find` commands.
3. You *will* need two `find` commands, since you want to replace *all* dots in directory names, but keep the last dot in filenames.
4. You are searching for filenames which contain spaces (`* *`). Is that intentional?

Comment: Also need to avoid the initial `./`, and the last dot that introduces the extension. So `(?<!^)\.(?=.*\.)` for perlre.

Comment: @4ae1e1 & @l0b0 Neither `(?<!^)\.(?=.*\.)` or `s/\./-/g` worked I have no change. The command runs, no error.

Comment: @l0b0, No `(* *)` "SPACES" was/are not intentional `(*.*)` "DOT" is the correct search pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to a variable and pipe like this:

```
x="dir.dir.dir/dir.dir.dir/file.file.file.ext"
echo "$(echo "Result: ${x%.*}" | sed 's/\./_/g').${x##*.}"
Result: dir_dir_dir/dir_dir_dir/file_file_file.ext
```