# how to remove spaces from a field in mySQL db?

Tags: mysql

I have a database where i store my photos title, tags, and their path on sever some of the records have names like:
  `photo 1234.png`. I need to make them like `photo1234.png`

Why can't I use a query like

```
UPDATE tblPhoto a
  set a.photoLink = replace(a.photoLink , ' ', '')
  where a.photoLink like '% %';
```

And which is the best way to rename them in Linux Server, can I use php ?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't I use a query like"? Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: I have safe mode turned ON and that throws this error " You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column."

Comment: Please edit your question and add that info. Also post how you execute that query (eg. workbench, CLI or some application language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `where` clause

```
UPDATE tblPhoto SET photoLink = REPLACE(photoLink , ' ', '');
```

For replacing the file name on your Linux Server you can try to look in this answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709619/7921383

Answer (score 0):

> Use php method for example:

```
$old_name="Hello World";
echo str_replace(" ","",$old_name);
```

*//output Helloworld*