# Replacing both spaces and " - " in filenames and directorys

Tags: linux, bash, whitespace

I have been reading this [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709458/how-to-replace-spaces-in-file-names-using-a-bash-script) and this `find . -depth -name '* *' \ | while IFS= read -r f ; do mv -i "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f"|tr ' ' _)" ; done`
helps me deleting spaces in files and directories.
`Beat Boy` becomes `Beat_Boy`. This is ok.
What I don't get  right is how to deal with this:
`Beat Boy - Best of` becomes `Beat_Boy_-_Best_of` while I want it to be `Beat_Boy-Best_of`.
I would appreciate any hint which way to go...

Regards

Comment: My hint would be to forget about removing spaces in filenames. I can understand the urge, but in the end, you'll find some elegance in having spaces and hence more natural looking filenames. After all, how readable, legible or elegant is a filename like `Beat_Boy-Best_of`?

Comment: Use the `rename` command instead of writing a bash script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `sed` to substitute "_-_" with "-"

```sh
f="Beat Boy - Best of"

echo $f | tr ' ' _ | sed 's/_-_/-/g'
#Beat_Boy-Best_of
```

In your case, you would want:

```sh
find . -depth -name '* *' | 
    while IFS= read -r f ; do 
        mv -i "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f" |
            tr ' ' _ |
            sed 's/_-_/-/g')" ; 
    done
```

**Edit**

You can also replace `tr ' ' _ | sed 's/_-_/-/g'` with `sed 's/ /_/g ; s/_-_/-/g'`.

Comment: Yea, if yer gonna use `sed` though, you can just chain both commands into one `echo "Beat Boy - Best of" | sed 's/ /_/g ; s/_-_/-/g'`

Comment: I now have the suggested changes applied and I am testing, as of now, it looks like it does what it is supposed to:  `#!/bin/bash

find . -depth -name '* *' \
| while IFS= read -r f ; do mv -i "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f" \
|sed 's/ /_/g ; s/_-_/-/g')" ; done`

Comment: @skeebolt - You can click to accept the answer if it solved your question. It will let others know that the question has been solved. You can also upvote any answers here that you think are useful or can also solve your question. Cheers.

Comment: I think LC-datascientist suggestion was the most helpful yet the other answers helped me to understand further dealing with such problems.        I will now try to rename only the filenames (not the dirs) from uppercase first letter to lowercase to avoid a mixture of both...

Answer (score 0):

```
f="Beat Boy - Best of"
f1=${f// - /-}
f1=${f1// /_}
echo $f1

Beat_Boy-Best_of
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution just replaces any number of [ ' ' or '-' ] with a single '_'. I assume that's probably what you want.

The `find` command still only searches for files with spaces in them, but you can change that to suit your needs.

```sh
while IFS= read -r f ;
    mv -i "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f" | sed -re 's/[ -]+/_/g')";
done < <(find . -depth -name '* *')
```

Full credit: this takes LC-datascientist's solution and replacing the somewhat awkward combination of `tr` and `sed`. Even Doyousketch2's comment about sed didn't use s///g option to make it simpler.