# In bash, is there a better solution for iterating through a directory and modifying a single character in some folders?

Tags: linux, bash

On Bash, I used the following script to replace the empty spaces in some directories with an underscore:

```
for dir in */; do
mv "${dir}" "${dir// /_}"
done
```

This did the trick but still received unnecessary output for directories that did not have an empty space to be replaced:

```
mv: cannot move 'directory1' to a subdirectory of itself, 'directory1/directory1'
```

Is there a more succinct way to carry this out in bash that doesn't result in a message for each of those directories that was unaffected?

Thanks

Comment: You could start with a `find` expression that would produce a list of directories that contain one or more spaces in their name, and see where that takes you. Or just stick an `if` statement in your existing loop...

Comment: `if test "$dir" != "${dir// /_}"; then mv "${dir}" "${dir// /_}"; fi`

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace

```
for dir in */
```

with

```
for dir in *\ */
```

You may also consider setting `nullglob` option (`shopt -s nullglob`) before the `for` loop.

Comment: FWIW, matching only source names containing the character we want to rename is covered in the duplicate at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710485/14122

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18213120/14122 is a nonrecursive version, thus basically identical to this answer (except a bit more comprehensive, as it doesn't elide the `mv` itself).

Answer (score 0):

You may like to consider using a command line tool designed for this kind of task. Two I regularly use are `rename` and `detox`.

```
$ mkdir -p 'foo bar/bar foo'
$ rename --nono --fullpath 's/\s+/_/' *
rename(foo bar, foo_bar)
$ detox --dry-run *
foo bar -> foo_bar
foo bar/bar foo -> foo bar/bar_foo
```

Note that rename is not recursive whereas detox is. Rename is a `perl` program so you can use `PCRE` regexes.

If you need to recurse with rename you can do the following:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ rename --nono --fullpath 's/\s+/_/' **
rename(foo bar, foo_bar)
rename(foo bar/bar foo, foo_bar/bar foo)
```

Comment: Both `rename` and `detox` are already covered by answers in [the very longstanding duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709458/how-to-replace-spaces-in-file-names-using-a-bash-script).